# Cronjobs not running with wget settings

Tags: cron

Is there a reason why below is not working?

```
0 10 * * * wget --tries=1 --timeout=99999 -O send-notifications.txt http://domain.com/send-notifications/
```

I have others such as below but they are working fine:

```
0 3 * * * wget --tries=1 --timeout=99999 -O task-scheduler.txt http://domain.com/task-scheduler
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: not running at all without logging anything to the text file

Comment: Change `wget` for the full path of wget, that you can get with `which wget`

Comment: ok why is the below one working?